# Connect perl to ms access

Tags: perl, ms-access-2007

I am tring to retrive data from a table in access. The code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use DBI;  
my $DBFile  = qw(C:test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb );   
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:driver=microsoft access driver (*.mdb);dbq=$DBFile",'','') or die("cannot connect to DB");  
my $SQLquery = "select * FROM IndemDate";  
$dbh->Execute($SQLquery);
```

This is the error i recieve

```
DBI connect('driver=microsoft access driver (*.mdb);dbq=C:test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/Test/connectaccess.pl line 9.
cannot connect to DB at C:/Test/connectaccess.pl line 9.
```

can someone help me rectify my error. Is there any driver I've missed to install.

Comment: try using `my $DBFile = 'C:/test/INSTRUCTIONS.mdb'; die "troubles with path of the file" if not -e $DBFile;` maybe there are troubles with passing that argument.. you can use that lines to check if it is like i wrote.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an ODBC connection through the control panel to make sure that side of things is OK?

Comment: @FilippoLauria it did not work that way either

Comment: @RichardHuxton I've performed SQL connection successfully, which proves ODBC connection is ok rite..

Comment: Check for a typo in the driver-name. Make sure it matches *exactly* what's listed in the `Data Sources (ODBC)` control panel. Oh, you don't want `qw()` on the filename setup, you probably meant `q()`.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I still recieve the same error if I relpace `qw()` with `q()`

Comment: Post your latest code. Make sure you put a slash after C:

Comment: Is your Perl script running as a 64-bit process?

Comment: How did you finally get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments to the question, the Perl script was originally running as a 64-bit process. Therefore the older Microsoft "Jet" ODBC driver

```
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
```

was not available. Only 32-bit processes can use the older Jet driver. If you *must* run your Perl script as a 64-bit process then you will have to download and install the 64-bit version of the newer Microsoft Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and then use the driver name

```
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
```

Or, you could run your Perl script as a 32-bit process and use the older Jet driver.

**Edit re: comment**

Since you have 32-bit Access 2007 installed you already have a 32-bit version of the ACE driver on the machine. That effectively eliminates the option to install the 64-bit version of the ACE driver because the 64-bit ACE installer will abort if it finds 32-bit Office components on the machine. (There is apparently a way to force the second install but it is reported to break Office in some circumstances and is definitely **not** supported.)

So your options can be revised to:

1. Run the Perl script as a 32-bit process, or
2. Remove 32-bit Access 2007 and install a 64-bit version of Access, then run the Perl script as a 64-bit process using the 64-bit ACE driver.

Comment: but i am using ms access 2007

Comment: @Programmer Is it 32-bit Access 2007? (I honestly don't remember if there was a 64-bit version of Access 2007.)

Comment: ms access 32-bit is what i am running on a 64 bit OS

Comment: yes but if I execute the program it returns the error... what is the error in my program

Comment: @Programmer Are you saying that you are now running the Perl script as a 32-bit process and you are still getting an error?

Comment: yes.... that is the reason why I have menntioned if i have missed installing any driver

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Jet`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;

my $DBFile  = qw( C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb );

# choose the appropriate versione of Jet for your system
my $Jet = Win32::OLE->CreateObject('DAO.DBEngine.36') or die "Can't create Jet database engine.";

my  $DB = $Jet->OpenDatabase( $DBFile );
my $SQLquery = "select * FROM IndemDate";
$DB->Execute($SQLquery, 128); #128=DBFailOnError
```

[source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-ms-access-database-using-perl), also have a look [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=272019)]

Comment: `Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80040154: "Class not registered" at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 10. Can't create Jet database engine. at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 10.`  This is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

For a script running as a 32-bit process (in my case, 32-bit Strawberry Perl), the following code works for me:

```
#!perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use DBI;  
print 'bits: ' . (8 * (length pack 'P', -1)) . "\n\n";
my $DBFile = q(C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb);   
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$DBFile",'','') or die("cannot connect to DB");  
my $SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM Members";  
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQLquery);
my $rc = $sth->execute;
while (my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print "memberID: " . $$href{"memberID"} . "\n";
    print "memberName: " . $$href{"memberName"} . "\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: no i still get the error `DBI connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 6.
cannot connect to DB at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 6.
`

Comment: I am using active perl

Comment: @Programmer Try adding the statement `print 'bits: ' . (8 * (length pack 'P', -1)) . "\n\n";` right near the beginning of your script. (See revised code, above.) What does it print?

Comment: `DBI connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.
cannot connect to DB at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.
`

Comment: @Programmer Once you added the extra statement did the script not print anything *before* the error message?

Comment: @Programmer ...so it appears that your script is still running as a 64-bit process. See my other answer.

Comment: so how to run the program as 32-bit process

Comment: @Programmer You may need to install a 32-bit version of the Perl interpreter and then use it to execute your script. It would probably be prudent to do a bit of searching to see if ActivePerl has a way to do that with the setup you have now. (Maybe 64-bit ActivePerl installs 32-bit components, too... I don't know.)