# Does 64 bit perl includes all 32 bit perl modules?

Tags: perl, ms-access-2007

I've got 64-bit operating system on which I have installed 64-bit perl. I've been given a task to retrieve data from a  table in MS Access 2007 (ms access is 32 bit). The program code that I try to execute pops up with an error which says

```
DBI connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.
cannot connect to DB at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.
```

The code is

```
#!perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use DBI;  
my $DBFile = q(C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb);   
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$DBFile",'','') or die("cannot connect to DB");  
my $SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM IndemDate";  
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQLquery);
my $rc = $sth->execute;
while (my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
print "memberID: " . $$href{"memberID"} . "\n";
print "memberName: " . $$href{"memberName"} . "\n";
print "\n";
}
```

So I was wondering if 64 bit perl include all 32 bit modules... or is there any mistake in the connection to ms access. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program works fine if I execute the program with 32-bit perl.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any Access related module here. There is no 64/32 bit issue. You are using an ODBC driver which is part of your OS, not Perl. Set up a system ODBC datasource for the file. Once you have this set up your code should take the general form:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

#open connection to Access database
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:ODBCNameGoesHere');
```

Comment: but i have mentioned `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` in my program... is that not sufficient?

Comment: @Programmer change `die("cannot connect to DB");` to `die("cannot connect to DB: $!");` to find out the reason why it's not working

Comment: but i have mentioned `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` in my program... is that not sufficient? @Dr.Avalanche

Comment: this is what i get `DBI connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,)};DBQ=C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7. cannot connect to DB: at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.`

Comment: this is what i get `DBI connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,)};DBQ=C:\test\INSTRUCTIONS.mdb','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7. cannot connect to DB: at C:/test/connectaccess.pl line 7.`

Comment: There is definitely a 64/32-bit issue related to the versions of the Microsoft Access ODBC drivers available to 64-bit and 32-bit processes. See the OP's earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21675186/2144390).