# Not able to connect to .accdb file using perl

Tags: perl, ms-access-2007

I am trying to connect to access 2007 database using perl. Below is the code that I tried executing

```
use DBI;

$path='T:\a\abc.accdb';
$datasource = "driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=$path";
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:$datasource", '', '') || die "Error connecting: $!";
$query="select name from receiver";
$exe=$dbh->prepare($query) or die "cannot prepare";
$exe->execute or die "cannot execute";

$a=$exe->fetchall_arrayref();
foreach $aa(@{$a})
{
print @$aa;
}
```

but the execution fails with the below error

`DBI connect('driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=T:\a\abc.accdb','',...)failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at test.pl line 5.
Error connecting:  at test.pl line 5.`

can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to an MS Access database using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651585/how-do-i-connect-to-an-ms-access-database-using-perl)

Comment: @Borodin if I do that way i am getting an error at execute cannot execute at test.pl line 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your driver name is missing a space. ODBC is very fussy about that. Try

```perl
$datasource = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=$path";
```

Also, `NAME` is a reserved word in Access SQL so you may need to use

```perl
$query="select [name] from receiver";
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with DBI:ODBC is somewhat dated but I would suggest the following:

- Check the driver names in the ODBC datasource setup and make sure 
  that you have the spelling right. (spaces and all) - Maybe set up a
  DSN and use that instead - more reliable
- Check that the file exists (I don't think that is the problem from
  the error message)
- Capitalization on the Driver/Dbq (not likely but we are dealing with
  MS)

Comment: all are fine.. cannot create a separate DSN as I have to do the same on many other database

Comment: the error message reporting the file as `T:a\ ` where you entered `T:\a\ ` is curious.